STM32F0 Jump to bootloader from application
I have a custom board with an STM32F042C4T6 where I use usart2 to load the firmware. Unfortunately on the connector I only have rx-tx-gnd and to load via usart I have to set the boot0 pin high. I would like to point out that boot0 is in pulldown via a resistor. Doing the first tests by putting in high boot0 the firmware loading works without problems. The only thing is that in the future I won't be able to access the PCB and therefore I can't set the boot0 pin high manually. Searching the web I found a couple of pieces of information about jumping memory from the application to the bootloader so I can recall it when I need it. I leave you below the function that I tried without success. The memory address is: 0x1FFFC400. If I try to connect with cube programmer it gives me an error telling me to check the connections and/or the status of the boot pin. Anyone who can help me? Thank you
Function:
* Function to perform jump to system memory boot from user application
 *
 * Call function when you want to jump to system memory
 */
void JumpToBootloader(void) {
    void (*SysMemBootJump)(void);
    
    /**
     * Step: Set system memory address. 
     *       
     *       For STM32F429, system memory is on 0x1FFF 0000
     *       For other families, check AN2606 document table 110 with descriptions of memory addresses 
     */
    volatile uint32_t addr = 0x1FFFC400;
    
    /**
     * Step: Disable RCC, set it to default (after reset) settings
     *       Internal clock, no PLL, etc.
     */
#if defined(USE_HAL_DRIVER)
    HAL_RCC_DeInit();
#endif /* defined(USE_HAL_DRIVER) */
#if defined(USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER)
    RCC_DeInit();
#endif /* defined(USE_STDPERIPH_DRIVER) */
    
    /**
     * Step: Disable systick timer and reset it to default values
     */
    SysTick->CTRL = 0;
    SysTick->LOAD = 0;
    SysTick->VAL = 0;
 
    /**
     * Step: Disable all interrupts
     */
    __disable_irq();
    
    /**
     * Step: Remap system memory to address 0x0000 0000 in address space
     *       For each family registers may be different. 
     *       Check reference manual for each family.
     *
     *       For STM32F4xx, MEMRMP register in SYSCFG is used (bits[1:0])
     *       For STM32F0xx, CFGR1 register in SYSCFG is used (bits[1:0])
     *       For others, check family reference manual
     */
    //Remap by hand... {
#if defined(STM32F0)
    SYSCFG->CFGR1 = 0x01;
#endif
    //} ...or if you use HAL drivers
    //__HAL_SYSCFG_REMAPMEMORY_SYSTEMFLASH();    //Call HAL macro to do this for you
    
    /**
     * Step: Set jump memory location for system memory
     *       Use address with 4 bytes offset which specifies jump location where program starts
     */
    SysMemBootJump = (void (*)(void)) (*((uint32_t *)(addr + 4)));
    
    /**
     * Step: Set main stack pointer.
     *       This step must be done last otherwise local variables in this function
     *       don't have proper value since stack pointer is located on different position
     *
     *       Set direct address location which specifies stack pointer in SRAM location
     */
    __set_MSP(*(uint32_t *)addr);
    
    /**
     * Step: Actually call our function to jump to set location
     *       This will start system memory execution
     */
    SysMemBootJump();
    
    /**
     * Step: Connect USB<->UART converter to dedicated USART pins and test
     *       and test with bootloader works with STM32 Flash Loader Demonstrator software
     */
}


You said nothing about what exactly goes wrong. Does it hardfault? Does it hang somewhere? What happens instead of the expected behavior? Nothing in your code seems off at first glance. You set the stack pointer, set jump address to reset handler. Seems correct. Make sure interrupts are enabled where they need to be (after IRQ disable), and make sure vector table offset is configured.

To jump back to bootloader you need to use NVIC_SystemReset();. You are even able to pass data between application and bootloader if you create a data section somewhere in RAM in your .ld file, because RAM won't get reset when you trigger NVIC_SystemReset();.
